# Overstayed UK Tier 4 student visa

Tags: visas, uk, overstaying

In 2011, I went to Bournemouth to study English, but I overstayed for almost 4 months after my visa expired. It has been 5 years since I left the UK.

Now, I would like to apply for a visa, to visit a friend, but I'm afraid to risk a refusal. Will my overstay affect an application for a tourist visa?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be considered as a factor in your tourist visa. Usually the application will ask you if you have ever violated the terms of a previous visa and give you a box for details. Depending on your situation, they might or might not give you the visa.

Comment: They never ask you that for a visit visa for the UK. They might have the details of the overstay though.

Comment: Yes they do. Part 2, length of visit. Also, there is a question: HAVE YOU ENGAGED IN ANY OTHER ACTIVITIES THAT MIGHT INDICATE THAT YOU MAY NOT BE ADMITTED TO THE UK?

Comment: that question is so vague they have had to remove it from the new forms.

Comment: I applied for a UK visa less than 2 months ago and this question was there on the form. Are you saying that you applied more recently than that and this question was not there on the form?